# Create a swipe between pages with CSS and JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, iframe, css-transitions, swipe

I'm trying to mock up a smartphone swipe navigation in HTML+CSS+JQuery.
I'm setting few iframes that includes my HTML pages and then swipe between them from a navigation menu. that's nice, but I want the swipe to be activated from buttons inside the iframes (the "Back to the menu" buttons on the example)

This is what I did so far:
[Example](http://smartdrive.me.cc/)

The code I used to create the swipe effect is:

**JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#slide1_controls').on('click', 'button', function(){
         $("#slide1_images").css("transform","translateX("+($(this).index()-2) * -475+"px)"); 
     });
 });
```

Can I do something like that but with buttons from inside the iframes?

**Note:** In each page I'll have an inside swipe effect as well: this will be implemented by swiping between divs and not iframes, so changing the given iframes into divs will probably won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn what you wrote into a function, and then call that function from inside the iframe.

```
//// on parent page
function slidePage(){
    // slide logic goes here
}

//// inside iframe
$('#slide-control').on('click', function(){
    window.parent.slidePage()
});
```

---

note your iframe and site must have the same domain for this to work.

Comment: I had some problems with the functions declarations. "window.parent.funcName()" was what I needed. Now it works :), thanks